# Find latitude and longitude from starting point of route finding in Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to find latitude and longitude from starting point of route finding in Google Map api v3. Because through these latitude and longitude, i have to find [store location](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) nearby starting point like :

`searchLocationsNear(lat,lng);`

Code:-

```
function calcRoute() {

      var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
      var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
      var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
         searchLocationsNear(lat,lng);
    }
```

In above code inside start variable location will be like `St. Louis`

Comment: Eh, isn't that what you already have in the `start` variable ?

Comment: @adeneo, in start name of location will be enter like St. Louis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took some time to set up a fiddle and figure it out, but this is how you'd get the latitude and longitude

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var position = response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location;
        var lat = position.k;
        var lng = position.B;

        searchLocationsNear(lat, lng);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kgLr138q/)